# Win8/7/XP print spooler not getting along with Zebra ZT230 via WIFI

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-xp, print-spooler, zebra-printer

I have a graphics-intensive 4"x6" label I'm printing to the ZT230. I'm printing multiple (10) copies.

When connected via USB, all goes well. However, when connected via wifi, I only get 2 of the labels.

A wireshark capture shows that at some point in the process my computer (presumably my windows spooler) is sending a reset packet, which, I believe, would pretty much kill the print job.

I'm getting the same results on Win8, Win7 and WinXP.

The print job was originally generated on Zebra's ZebraDesigner2 software. For easier diagnosis, I captured it to a .prn file.

The .prn file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwxF_9SAkKzLLTF5bUJVT0lESUU/edit?usp=sharing

And the wireshark capture file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwxF_9SAkKzLTGpSS0ktZW1xV28/edit?usp=sharing

And the printer configuration listing: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zh1Tw4D4yNa2uljOIL1kO2z8se9HK859irpUEwyxlyY/edit?usp=sharing

I've started a discussion with Zebra Tech Support, and they're working on it, but I thought I'd toss it out here for more ideas since we're getting kind of stumped.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the port in Windows was set to Advanced Port Monitor. Changed it to Standard TCP/IP port and everything worked fine.